# Как сделать свой переключатель цифр в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Нужно что бы верхняя стрелка меняла значение в input на +1, а нижняя на -1. минимальное значение было 0, а максимальное 9. помогите пожалуйста
[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/mars_092/6jhoun0t/5/)

```
<ul class="test">
  <li class="entering-numbers">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    <input type="text" value="4" readonly>
    <label> 123</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var up = document.getElementById('up');
var down = document.getElementById('down');

function isValid(n) {
 let min = 0;
 let max = 9;
    if (n >= min && n <= max) {
     return true;
    }
    return false;
}

up.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 let n = parseInt(input.value);
    ++n;
 let val = isValid(n);
 if(!!val) {
  input.value = n;
     console.log("Inc: %d", n);
    }
});

down.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 let n = parseInt(input.value);
    --n;
 let val = isValid(n);
 if(!!val) {
  input.value = n;
     console.log("Dec: %d", n);
    }
});
```

```css
.entering-numbers > input {
 width: 15px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px 40px 0;
 height: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #efbd16;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: none;
 color: #1c1c1c;
 font-family: GothamPro;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 500;
} .entering-numbers > label:after {
 display: none;
}
.entering-numbers > label:befor {
 display: none;
}

.arrow-up {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
     top: 4px;
    left: 49px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #efbd16;
}
.arrow-down {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
     top: 36px;
    left: 49px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #efbd16;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li class="entering-numbers">
    <div class="arrow-up" id="up"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" id="down"></div>
    <input type="text" value="4" id="input" readonly>
    <label> 123</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо и вам)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста еще, а если таких input со стрелками несколько на странице. этот код тогда не работает. как такое реализовать?

Comment: Использовать не id, а другой селектор. Например data-id.